# PHP: How to filter invisible ASCII characters?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, internationalization, filter

Anybody know a good way of filtering non visible and rare characters from a string in PHP?

I'm in a situation where I am parsing a news article text from a website, I'm doing a bunch of  'normalizations' e.g. removing double new lines, stripping tags and such. The problem is I stumbled uppon some weird invisible characters, when I call `ord()` I get 194 and 160.. they do not belong there. The thing is such characters appear in between new paragraphs, so when the text is rendered it seems like there is a double new line, since there are 2 paragraphs with an invisible character in between.

This aside it would still be nice if I could easily filter anything but latin, cyrillic, numbers and common characters like *, (, % etc. I could make a map with all of them and replace the rest, but what would be the easiest and fastest way to do this?

Comment: ASCII only defines 128 characters - there are no ASCII characters 194 and 160. You should [read up on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: iso-8859-1, -2, -3, -4, -9, -10, -14, -15, -16  define `160` as a non-breaking space and `194` as the Latin capital A with circumflex. -5 defines 194 as Cyrillic capital TE `Т`, -6 defines 194 as an Arabic Alef with Madda above `` آ, -7 defines 194 as a Greek capital Beta `Β`, -8 doesn't define 194, -11 defines 194 as Thai Yo Yak `ย`, -13 defines 194 as Latin capital A with Macron (but my manpage shows a `Β` when using the `terminus` iso-10646 fonts; go figure).

Comment: The question seems valid. Surely just a little editing is required to correct a slight oversight on the part of the writer.

Comment: if its an all english news letter you can filter out any ord() higher then 127.

Comment: It would seem to me that you are parsing the article using the wrong encoding, or perhaps that you are ignoring encodings altogether.

Comment: @AMayer Thinking that "English" exclusively consists of the 128 ASCII characters is exactly the wrong attitude towards encodings and source of a lot of encoding problems... :)

Comment: @AMayer That’s pure nonsense. English properly written has always required more than mere ASCII, and to pretend otherwise is but a *naïve façade*. Ever heard of £10-pound note, or a 5¢ piece of candy? How about *c = πr²* ? Never had a friend named Zoë or Renée? Ever been to Cañon City, Colorado? Ever used “curly quotes” or ‘apostrophes’ — or em dashes? How about Copyright © 2012? What about 350 µg? Or 10.2 ± 0.6? Or 2 × 3 ≠ 7? How about 86°F or 30°C? Ever needed ¼ cup of sugar? Been told to see §4.3? Is 5 ÷ 0 anything like ∞? What about Commercial™ Marks®

Comment: i wasnt saying this would work in every case. @Tony asked if there was a way he could have letters and "common characters"(see: *, (, % etc.) they are all included in the first 128 chars. no its not fool proof but if the person making the news letter only uses none accented letter and types out Pi or infinity then this solution would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article and my script are both in the same 'locale' or whatever it is called - it uses windows-1251 with cyrillic characters, the parsing is correct, but the poster has managed to insert a weird character while typing the news article.

I've made a `preg_replace` regex to remove anything but characters, numbers and some common symbols, it works for me.

@phihag The article was interesting, but did not answer my question, only showed me that it wasn't asked correctly and made me feel dumb.